# Reading and storing Java Icons

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, imageicon

In my Java application I'm planning to use a lot of `ImageIcon`s which will be shown in `JLabel`s. The size of a single `.png` file is about 8 kB. During runtime, icons will be shown in `JLabel`s, but the icons shown in the labels will change often, using `.setIcon(icon)`.

Should I load all those icons at once when the program starts and store those in an array (length would be > 150) or should I load the icons every time I change an Icon as shown in the code below?

Note that the number of `JLabel`s is rather small, so, at a given moment, only a selection of icons is shown.

```
ClassLoader cl = getClass().getClassLoader();
String path = "somePath";
URL url = cl.getResource(path);
Icon icon = new ImageIcon(url);
```

The application will be a jar file with the resources inside the jar.

Comment: I would go with 'load them at start-up' unless `OutOfMemeryError` or visible app. slow down occurs.

Comment: depends, how many icons are there? 2-3 or 200+

Comment: @adhg: As I wrote above, the array would have length > 150, so at least that many icons. :)

Comment: @Andrew Thompsen: Yes, my concerns were also regarding possible OutOfMemory. It didn't happen so far (in Eclipse). Are there any other cons other than performance issues when I create/load an icon many times?. Basically, the changes would appear whenever my GUI is updated (for example, when a new State is received by the Server. But it's turn-based. There is no update every second or something like that.

Comment: I'll put it this way.  If an app. had a couple of hundred icons created from 8Kb pngs (always best to quote image width x height over KB as the files size of a compressed image can hold little information about how big it will be in memory) and saw OOME, I'd first be looking at other areas of the app. as the actual *cause* of a memory leak.  As far as memory leaks go, about the only thing in regard to images that I can think of that might cause one is use of `Image.getScaledInstance(..)` (spelling?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be a bit cliche, but "Do not optimize your application unless it needs to be optimized." It makes maintenance more difficult in future.

Because, every program evolves in time, and the kind of the optimization required may not be the one you are planning to do at the moment. Your JLabels may increase in number, or your possible icons may increase. Or some other new feature comes up and you may need to display all the icons at the same time etc. etc.

So, just write your code as clean as possible, and when you see that an optimization is really required, do it after measuring where is the bottle neck.

PS: I am telling this, because you write "I am planning to use" so you did not actually finished the application and saw the effect of this many icon loadings.

PS2: OS and Disk caches are getting better everyday, so it may just be enough for the time being.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I already had code in Eclipse where I load the Icons whenever there is a change. But recently I read in another Thread here at Stackoverflow (don't have a link now) that somebody recommended in general to load the icons at start-up. So, I thought I could need some hints, pros or cons, for example.

Comment: *"This will be a bit cliche, but.."* ..it needs repeating often, and loudly.  +1